# how to add the second css selector xpath where the same element appears more than once

Tags: java, selenium

how to add the second `css selector` or `xpath` where the same element appears more than once.

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("span.mat-content"));
```

I need to add the same `css selector again` but for the `2nd element`
how do it do that.

This is for the first one which I have added as seen above:

**HTML:**

`<span class="mat-content ng-tns-c143-2587">` = first one

HTML which I need to add -

`<span class="mat-content ng-tns-c143-2589">` = How do I add the `css selector` using this `html tag`.

`WebElement element2 = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("span.mat-content"));` = In this place how do I add it for the second element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
List<WebElement> elements= driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("span.mat- 
content"));
WebElement element2 = elements.get(1);
```

Should work

Answer (score 3):

If this `span.mat-content` represent multiple web element in HTMLDOM.

You can use `findElements` to grab them all.

```
List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("span.mat-content"));
```

Now `elements` is a list in Java-Selenium bindings.

You could do, `elements.get(1)` and this shall represent the second web element.

or You can iterate the entire list like this:

```
for (WebElement element : elements){
    element.getText(); //Note that each `element` is a web web element. 
}
```

If you do not wish to have the above way. You can try **xpath indexing**.

```
(//span[contains(@class,'span.mat-content')])[1]
```

should represent the first element.

and

```
(//span[contains(@class,'span.mat-content')])[2]
```

should represent the second element and so on..

```
[3], [4], .... [n]
```

just replace css with xpath. xpath indexing is not preferred choice.